# Microsoft Graph API - Is there a way to get all the service principals?

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Using this query https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/serviceprincipals , it shows 100 service principals, whereas the total count is 215 with this query https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/$count

How can I get the entire list of serviceprincipals?

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/serviceprincipal-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Default, Most of the REST APIs including Graph API returns a result of 100 records. if you want all the data you need to make use of [count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#count-parameter) and [top](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#top-parameter) together or skip which acts similar to pagination.

[https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/$top="totalCount"](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/$top=%22totalCount%22)

Answer (score 0):

I used a trick to get all the service principles by adding this query parameter
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/$top=215

Comment: This query works on 'Try out' on the doc. On Microsoft Graph, use `/servicePrincipals?$top={totalCount}`