# Way to query in Microsoft Graph API using $filter with multiple condition

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm wanna query like the condition below.

**"E5 Licensed Users with LastSignInDateTime Delayed by More than 30 Days"**

The method I used for the query is as follows.

```
$skuID = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2020-08-01T00:00:00Z and (assignedLicenses @{skuId} eq "c7df2760-2c81-4ef7-b578-5b5392b571df")' -Headers $Headers
```

but it doesn't work.

Invoke-RestMethod : {
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Invalid filter clause",
"innerError": {
"date": "2020-08-31T11:46:15",
"request-id": "eeb58015-c6c2-437d-af1d-93227224133e"
}
}
}
위치 줄:1 문자:10

- $skuID = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/use ...
- ```
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Is there any way?

+And if you look up the user in API, only 100 people can be inquired. Is there a way to check all users?

this is Graph API's limit what I found.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling#pattern

Comment: Please try this Graph api in graph explorer `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2020-08-01T00:00:00Z&assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq XXX7a907fd6c235)&$select=id,displayname` and let us know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this Graph API in graph explorer

**Get** `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2020-08-01T00:00:00Z&assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq XXX7a907fd6c235)&$select=displayname`

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
I have one more question, 
Graph API has a limitation, Now is only 100 people can be inquired. 

Is there a way to check all users?

Comment: @ciscons `/users?$top={totalCount}` will help. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63644113/13308381).

Comment: You will get top 999 users using this query `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$Top=999&$filter=signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime le 2020-08-01T00:00:00Z&assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq XXX7a907fd6c235)&$select=displayname` for iteration please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/paging?tabs=csharp)

Comment: According to the documentation "and" is the right way to filter on multiple properties.
Using & instead is the url syntax for another property, thus not considered part of filter.
In my test the query was accepted, but the part after & ignored.

According to the thread here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7228,
a signInActivity/lastSignInDateTime filter cannot be combined with filtering on other properties. I have not seen that in Microsofts documentation, but fits what I experience.